# How can I remove trailing slash with .htaccess on localhost with UniServer

Tags: apache-2.2, rewrite, localhost

I want to remove the last trailing slash of a URL. For example: I want to `http://localhost/mysite/page/` rewrite to `http://localhost/mysite/page`.

I'm using this code on my localhost .htaccess.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine   on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ $1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ web.php?page=$1
```

If I write on my browser `http://localhost/mysite/index`, it shows what I want. But if I write `http://localhost/mysite/index/` it tells me "not found" and "the requested URL was not found on this server". I'm using UniServer on Windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
# Remove trailing slash if not an existing directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

# Rewrite to use web.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web.php?page=$1 [L]
```

You may not need to change the second rule if it's already working fine.

Comment: If I write the same code, it doesn't work. If I write before it:

`Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on`

When I write `http://localhost/mysite/index` It shows me a problem with a redirect loop. And if I write `http://localhost/mysite/index/`, it redirects me to: `http://localhost/C:/UniServer/www/mysite/index`.


If I only write the first rule, it works for "index" but it redirects to the same with "index/".

Answer (score 0):

It worked adding this line

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /mysite/$1 [R,L]
```